# Probability of Deck of Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a poker game, a hand consists of drawing five cards at random from a deck of 52 cards (cards are arranged by 4 suits with 13 different numbers in each suit). Find the probabilities of each of the following occurrences and rank them according to their likelihood
>
> (a) Five different cards (none of the same number)

Wouldn't this just be $\displaystyle\frac{\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$?

> (b) Five different cards with all four suits represented

Wouldn't this be $1 \cdot \frac{39}{51} \cdot \frac{26}{50} \cdot \frac{13}{49}$?

> (c) Two pairs (i.e. two of a kind)

I have no idea how to do this one.

> (d) Playing a modified version of the game, two cards are placed face up for anyone to see. If the two cards face up in a hand are both 10's, what is the probability of the hand having two pairs?

I have no idea to do this one.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Please show your own work at solving this, and indicate just where your trouble is.  People prefer to help out those they see trying to help themselves.

Comment: I do not understand the rationale for your answer in part (a).  Your answer for part (b) would be correct if four cards are selected.  Since five cards are selected, there must be two cards drawn from one of the suits and one card drawn from each of the remaining suits.

Comment: I meant 13C5/52C5

Comment: In part (b), did you mean five cards of different ranks with all four suits represented or just that all four suits are represented among the five cards?

Answer (score 1):

> > (a) Five different cards (none of the same number)
>
> Wouldn't this just be 13C5/52C5?

No.  You seek the probability for obtaining *five from thirteen* kinds **each** of *one from four* suits, when selecting *five from fifty-two* cards.$$\dfrac{{^{13}\mathrm C_5}~({^4\mathrm C_1})^5}{^{52}\mathrm C_5}$$

> > (b) Five different cards with all four suits represented
>
> Wouldn't this be 1*39/51*26/50*13/49?

You seek the probability for obtaining *two from thirteen* kinds of the same *one from four suits* **and** *three from eleven* kinds each a distinct one from the three remaining suits, when selecting a hand.

> > c) Two pairs (i.e. two of a kind)

You seek the probability for obtaining *two from thirteen* kinds each of *two from four suits* **and** *one from eleven* kinds of *one from four* suits (aka one from fourty-four remaining card).

Note: This considers a pair to be "*exactly* two of a kind in the hand", so triples and quadruples are not counted.

> (d) Playing a modified version of the game, two cards are placed face up for anyone to see. If the two cards face up in a hand are both 10's, what is the probability of the hand having two pairs?

What is the probability for having a non-`10`s pair *and* a non-`10`s singleton among the *three* unflipped cards, when those cards were selected from the *fifty* cards that were not *that pair* of `10`s?